# Select count from subselect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have two tables SurrogateKeys and SurrogateKeyRelatives.

I will find out of there are records that satisfy a query joining both tables.

I am playing with two options:

```
select count(*) from 
(
    select top(1) sk.Username from SurrogateKeys as sk

    inner join SurrogateKeyRelatives as skr
    on sk.Id = skr.SurrKeyId

    where 

    sk.Username='John.Doe' and
    skr.SomeField = 1
)
```

and

```
if exists(
    select top(1) sk.Username from SurrogateKeys as sk

    inner join SurrogateKeyRelatives as skr
    on sk.Id = skr.SurrKeyId

    where 

    sk.Username='John.Doe' and
    skr.SomeField = 1
   )
   begin
    select 1
   end
else
    begin
      select 0
    end
```

Attempting option 1 gives me Incorrect Syntax near ')'.  What am I missing in the above query?

Comment: You need to give an alias to the derived table: `select count(*) from (/**your query here**/) AS SomeAlias`

Comment: Also you don't need to say TOP (1) inside EXISTS.

Comment: option 2 can be something like this... IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE Condition)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I do not want a full table scan, hence the top (1).

Comment: It's just noise, it doesn't do anything. Inside EXISTS SQL Server will short circuit as soon as it hits the first row anyway (and if it doesn't find one, TOP (1) will do a full scan anyway).

Comment: @KlausNji Without the top(1) that turns into a full table scan?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, ok, thanks.  I thought top(1) will short circuit as soon as the first row is obtained.

Comment: @Blam top(1) without top(1) I do not see a full table scan.  Guess I need to read more about exactly what top(n) does.

Comment: And you need to look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) from 
(
    select top(1) sk.Username from SurrogateKeys as sk

    inner join SurrogateKeyRelatives as skr
    on sk.Id = skr.SurrKeyId

    where 

    sk.Username='John.Doe' and
    skr.SomeField = 1
) Q1
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I did try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top(1)  
       CASE 
          WHEN skr.SurrKeyId is null THEN 0 
          ELSE 1 
       END 
  from SurrogateKeys as sk
  left join SurrogateKeyRelatives as skr
    on sk.Id = skr.SurrKeyId
   and sk.Username='John.Doe' 
   and skr.SomeField = 1
```

Comment: Blam, this is a good one, thanks. user2942261 did answer my question but this query is an interesting one.  It provides a simpler execution plan but takes almost double the CPU time as opposed to the version that returns count.  So decided to return count and in code check if count > 0.

Comment: I thought for sure it would be more efficient

Comment: SSMS is spitting out many more execution times just for the two queries so need to figure out what is what here.  Will take your word for it though and look into this option more.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in first option try to give inner query a table name after brace

```
select count(*) from 
(
    select top(1) sk.Username from SurrogateKeys as sk

    inner join SurrogateKeyRelatives as skr
    on sk.Id = skr.SurrKeyId

    where 

    sk.Username='John.Doe' and
    skr.SomeField = 1
) table1
```